# Task scheduler Issue

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have a console application for saving attachments from outlook mail. I schedule the application in windows task scheduler , when I select Run whether user is logged in or not scheduler is not opening the outlook and application is not working.it is working fine when I use run only user is logged in and I logged in with the account.

Comment: how can outlook run when no user is connected?

Comment: were there any errors in the Windows Event logs?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't do that. Outlook is a program that demands a user logged in in an interactive session to work, but a Task in the task manager doesn't have an interactive session.

You should programme that attachment download in a way that doesn't need an interactive session (a user logged in the computer).